# update column after insert using a trigger

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update a column using a trigger in SQL Server 2014 after I insert row in the competition table.

I need to update the judge_Id in the competition table from NULL to a judges_ID in the judges table. 
The judges_ID needs to be a swimming judge in the expertise table (it's a swimming contest).

Then I need to insert the competition.judges_ID with a count from the competition.judges_ID with a judges ID that has the lowest count. (i.e allocating a relevant judges workload evenly between the judges)

this is what I've tried.

I know it's not right because I'm not sure how to put Joins in.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_insertJudge]
   ON [dbo].[competition]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[competition.judges_ID]
   WITH [dbo].[judges.judges_ID]

   SELECT

   FROM [dbo].[judges.judges_ID] 

   WHERE [dbo].[judges.judges_ID] = [judges2expertise.judges_ID]

   AND

   [dbo].[judges2expertise.expertiseType] = 3

   SELECT 

   FROM [dbo].[judges.judges_ID] 

   WHERE 

   COUNT [dbo].[competition.judges_ID] 

   FROM [dbo.competition.judgesID]

   SELECT MIN [dbo.competition.judgesID]

END
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense, but if you add sample data, current results, and desired results, it might.

Comment: If you're writing a trigger, you should *somehow, somewhere* reference the `Inserted` pseudo table which contains the newly inserted rows - assuming you probably want to do something based on what rows have been inserted with your last statement.....

Comment: ok I've posted it here, hope you can access it [link](https://dangerousscion.smugmug.com/My-First-Gallery/i-gmFdgb6)

Comment: I'm trying to update the NULL (which is a SMALLINT) in competition

Comment: OK, looks like I'll have to try again